# Duvida sobre a utilização de classe

Tags: c#, sql, classes

Galera bom dia. 
Como vai?
Estou escrevendo um aplicativo windowsform, e em algumas situações preciso fazer varias consultas, insert e delete.. pois bem, então criei uma classe consulta, uma classe delete e uma classe insert, onde todos as minhas consultas eu jogo na classe consulta, todos os inserts na classe insert e assim por diante, isso esta certo? ou o certo seria criar uma classe para cada ação?

Segue parte do codigo da classe consulta:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Onee
{
    class consulta_bd
    {
        conexao_bd consql = new conexao_bd();

        public Dictionary<string, string> consulta_usuario(int id_usu)
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);

            Dictionary<string, string> dic_consulta_usuario = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT * FROM Login WHERE id_usu = @id_usu";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_usu", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id_usu;
                sqlconn.Open();

                SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (leitor.Read())
                {
                    dic_consulta_usuario.Add("usuario", leitor["usuario"].ToString());
                    dic_consulta_usuario.Add("password", leitor["password"].ToString());
                    dic_consulta_usuario.Add("nome", leitor["nome"].ToString());
                    dic_consulta_usuario.Add("sobrenome", leitor["sobrenome"].ToString());
                    dic_consulta_usuario.Add("email", leitor["email"].ToString());
                    dic_consulta_usuario.Add("tel", leitor["tel"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao gerar dicionario de dados usuario" + "\n" + error);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return dic_consulta_usuario;
        } // consulta ao clicar no gridiview gera um dicionario e retornar os valores.

        public int consulta_id_usuario()
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            int v;

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT COUNT(id_usu) FROM Login";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                v = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (v > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        consql._sql = @"SELECT id_usu FROM Login ORDER BY id_usu DESC";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                        v = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao consultar id do usuario no banco" + "\n" + error);
                        v = -1;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sqlconn.Close();
                    }

                    return v;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao consultar id do usuario no banco" + "\n" + error);
                v = -1;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return v;
        } //consultar o numero de registro que consta na tabela de login, para dar o numero de id do usario.

        public int consulta_usuario_jacadastrado(string usuario)
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            int v;

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT COUNT(id_usu) FROM Login WHERE usuario = @usuario";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario;
                sqlconn.Open();
                v = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao verificar se o usuario ja esta cadastrado" + error);
                v = -1;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return v;
        } // verifica se ja existe o usuario cadastrado.

        public int consulta_servidor()
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            int v;

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT COUNT(servidor) FROM Servidor_sql";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                v = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao buscar Servidor SQL" + error);
                v = -1;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return v;
        } // verifica se ja existe servidor cadastrado.

        public Dictionary<string, string> preenche_servidor()
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            Dictionary<string, string> dic_dados_servidor = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT * FROM Servidor_sql";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (leitor.Read())
                {
                    dic_dados_servidor.Add("servidor", leitor["servidor"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_servidor.Add("login", leitor["login"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_servidor.Add("password", leitor["password"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao buscar Servidor SQL" + error);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return dic_dados_servidor;
        } // preenche as infomraçoes do servidor no form.

        public Dictionary<string, string> preenche_empresa()
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            Dictionary<string, string> dic_dados_empresa = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT * FROM Empresa_man";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (leitor.Read())
                {
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("razao_social", leitor["razao_social"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("nome_fantasia", leitor["nome_fantasia"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("cnpj", leitor["cnpj"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("ie", leitor["ie"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("endereco", leitor["endereco"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("numero", leitor["numero"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("bairro", leitor["bairro"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("cidade", leitor["cidade"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("estado", leitor["estado"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("pais", leitor["pais"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("telefone", leitor["telefone"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("logo", leitor["logo"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_empresa.Add("id_empresa", leitor["id_empresa"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao buscar dados empresa" + error);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return dic_dados_empresa;
        } // preenche as infomraçoes da empresa no form.

        public int consulta_empresa()
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            int v;

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT COUNT(id_empresa) FROM Empresa_man";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                v = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao contar empresa" + error);
                v = -1;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return v;
        } // verifica se ja empresa cadastrada.

        public Dictionary<string, string> preenche_cliente(int id_v)
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            Dictionary<string, string> dic_dados_cliente = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT * FROM Cliente_man WHERE id_cliente = @id_cliente";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_cliente", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id_v;
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (leitor.Read())
                {
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("razao_social", leitor["razao_social"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("nome_fantasia", leitor["nome_fantasia"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("n_doc", leitor["n_doc"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("tipo_doc", leitor["tipo_doc"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("ie", leitor["ie"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("endereco", leitor["endereco"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("numero", leitor["numero"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("bairro", leitor["bairro"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("cidade", leitor["cidade"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("estado", leitor["estado"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("pais", leitor["pais"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("telefone", leitor["tel"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("email", leitor["email"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("im", leitor["im"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("cep", leitor["cep"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("bloqueado", leitor["bloqueado"].ToString());
                    dic_dados_cliente.Add("requisitos", leitor["requisitos"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao buscar dados cliente" + error);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return dic_dados_cliente;
        } // preenche as infomraçoes do cliente no form.

        public int consulta_id_cliente()
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            int v;

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT COUNT(id_cliente) FROM Cliente_man";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                v = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (v > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        consql._sql = @"SELECT id_cliente FROM Cliente_man ORDER BY id_cliente DESC";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                        v = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao consultar id do usuario no banco" + "\n" + error);
                        v = -1;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sqlconn.Close();
                    }

                    return v;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao consultar id do usuario no banco" + "\n" + error);
                v = -1;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return v;
        } //consultar o numero de registro que consta na tabela de cliente_man, para dar o numero de id do usario.

        public DataTable preenche_end_cobranca(int id_atual)
        {
            consql.bd_string();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);
            DataTable cobranca = new DataTable();
            DataTable entrega = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                consql._sql = @"SELECT id_cliente_alter,nome,endereco,numero,bairro,cidade,estado,cep FROM Cliente_enderecos_alter WHERE id_cliente = @id_cliente AND tipo = 'Cobrança'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_cliente", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id_atual;


                sqlconn.Open();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(cobranca);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }

            return cobranca;
        } // preenche as infomraçoes dos enderecos cobranca dos clientes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma classe deveria seguir o principio da responsabilidade única. Outra forma de ver isso é que ela deveria ter apenas um motivo para mudar. Da maneira que você construiu qualquer modificação que você faça no software provavelmente terá que modificar essas classes. Outra desvantagem é que com o tempo essas classes ficarão gigantescas e difícil de dar manutenção.

Um padrão de código bastante utilizado para abstrair as consultas ao banco é o Repository Pattern. Nesse você teria por exemplo uma classe  UsuarioRepository e nela estaria todas as consultas/inserts referentes ao modelo de usuário.

Comment: Verdade amigo, minha classe consulta esta bem grande mesmo, e as vezes me perco tentando achar algo. Obrigado pela orientação.